# How to allow all/ any extension files to upload in Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

How to allow all/ any extension files to upload in Google Drive picker from web apps?

I have allowed

```
mimeTypes: "image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,application/pdf,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/msword,application/msword",
```

I am not able to upload Kingsoft files (xlsx)

```js
function initPicker() {
  return {
    locale: 'en',
    token: ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    origin: "https://script.google.com",
    parentFolder: "0B0Oj_1v-CAzNYmFMRkVUZjd0aHM",
    developerKey: "AIzaSyBno-75vfzpW0hnBfagPrU1o5PxZ1yc8C8",
    dialogDimensions: {
      width: 600, 
      height: 425
    },
    picker: {
      viewMode: "LIST",
      mineOnly: true,
      mimeTypes: "image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg,application/pdf,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/msword,application/msword",
      multiselectEnabled: true,
      allowFolderSelect: true,
      navhidden: true,
      hideTitle: true,
      includeFolders: true,
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Have you tried not setting it at all?

Comment: Almost,yes i am able upload  MS office  Files

Comment: So... does that solve your problem?

Comment: No,not able to upload  wps  (kingsoft)files

Comment: What about using `application/*` or even `*/*`?

Comment: Ok , will check with this

Comment: I have tried replacing application/* or even */* still no luck facing same error while uploading error "File type not supported to upload "

Comment: Then probably Google just doesn't let you do it.

Comment: There is no such restriction...I was able to upload now....can you share the entire code?

Comment: @Ritz Sample Sheet _https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hjqqCDFE67aBWhckAQXNFM_jMRt-7mV0V2CT-J7TnsY/edit#gid=89955601

Comment: @KiranShety not a valid link

Comment: @ritz-  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hjqqCDFE67aBWhckAQXNFM_jMRt-7mV0V2CT-J7TnsY/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `mimeTypes` property and then you will be able to upload files of any type.

```
picker: {
      viewMode: "LIST",
      mineOnly: true,
      multiselectEnabled: true,
      allowFolderSelect: true,
      navhidden: true,
      hideTitle: true,
      includeFolders: true,
    }
```